# XSD to xml transformation is not right

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I have a xsd as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/api/2.2" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xml:lang="EN" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/api/2.2">
  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="domain" type="domain"/> <!-- changed here -->
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="timestamp" type="xs:normalizedString" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:token" fixed="2.2"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="domain"> <!-- and here -->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="account" type="uid" use="required">
      </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="uid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="36"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

and the xml generated through one online xsd to xml generator is like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration timestamp="str111" version="2.2">
    <domain account="str123400000000000000000000000000000" />
</configuration>
```

But when I am going to validate through javax.xml.validation.Validator it throwsfollowing exception

```
Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.; ;130503155804008299000002; ; WebContainer : 2;
```

and  this

```
 <COMMONS_ERROR>; ErrorThe Exception occured at Line No.1 Column  No.107; ; 130503155804008299000002; ; WebContainer : 2;
```

Please help me...to find out the right xml patten for the above xsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema defines elements within the namespace `http://www.example.com/api/2.2`

The generator seems to have ignored that.

Add a namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.example.com/api/2.2"` to `configuration` in the xml, and all will be well.